# How to make an element with fixed position relative to its parent, not the whole screen?

Tags: css

I run into situation that when user scroll down, a part of the sidebar gets fixed position, however when I catch the position and apply fixed css to the sidebar element, it gets fixed to whole screen, not just the parent (which is sidebar)

how do I setup this correctly?

Comment: `An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window.`

Comment: @Ahmed Fouad: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First Understand Positioning:

> ***Fixed Positioning* OR [ position:fixed ]**
>
> An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window.
>
> ***Relative Positioning* OR [ position:relative ]**
>
> A relative positioned element is positioned relative to its normal position.
>
> ***Absolute Positioning* OR [ position:absolute ]**
>
> An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.

So in your case your parent `div` should have `position:relative` and your child `div` should have `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed`

[Reference Link](http://w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: But position: absolute does not help, because i want to show the element on top of screen but still within the wrapper width.. (1000px for example)

Answer (score 7):

From reading your question I assume you have something like this:

```
 <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="fixed" style="position: fixed;"></div>
 </div>
```

Unfortunately as you probably know by now, `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom` will always act relative to the browser window on `positon: fixed` elements.

The solution is wrapping your `.fixed` div with another div, and do all the positioning you have to do on that same wrapper and not on the `.fixed` div. Let me demonstrate:

***The HTML:***

```
<div class="sidebar">

    <div class="helper">
        <div class="fixed"></div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

***The CSS:***

```
​.sidebar {
    position: relative;
}

.helper {
    position: absolute;
    top: XYZ; left: ZYX; /*where XYZ and ZYX would
                           be the values you were 
                           trying before to give to .fixed*/
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

See it in action in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/T2PL5/

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent `position: relative` then its children will use that as their reference for `absolute` positioning. For details see the [Definition of "containing block"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) in the [CSS 2 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/).

About `fixed` positioning: how can anything be fixed (which means fixed to the viewport) but still be relative to some other element, which in turn is not fixed to the viewport? This seems a contradiction to me, which is the reason why I first misunderstood your question.

Comment: As far as I know, that only works for `absolute`, not for `fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/sticky-sidebar-jquery-plugin/) is exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve this to be able to show a failing test case for a buggy full-screen modal. In fact, you can trap a `position: fixed;` element by applying CSS transform to the container. For example, a container's `transform: translate(200px);` will destroy its every full-screen nature. It will act like a normal div.

By reading further about this, transform is not the only property that cause this but also `filter`, and `perspective`.

To also answer the question, you cannot make it relative to the container similarly to the relative-absolute combination, but you can trap it inside the container which is also relative but without the effect of positioning and sizing of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`.