# fluid layout and position fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, twitter-bootstrap-3, fluid-layout

I have a problem with a fluid layout, made using bootstrap and a fixed element made by the bootstrap affix plugin.

What I’d like to achieve is a compound view like on Android tablets, where you have left a list of elements and when you click on one you see the details of that element on the right hand side.

My problem is that as soon as the plugin attaches the `affix` class to the right side it is taken “out” of the page and the width is strange. The `affix` class makes the element to have `position: fixed`. And that makes the width to no longer be relative to the parent, but to the document.

I’ve made a pen of my simplified testcase. You have to scroll to see the effect happening.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zDieo

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be add this to your css

```
.affix , .affix-top {

width: 800px;
}
```

Modified Code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gBHca

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But then the element wouldn't be fluid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KnzFr)

And read this - [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431358/how-to-make-an-element-with-fixed-position-relative-to-its-parent-not-the-whole)